# How does someone find an email account that I delegated to them in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When I delegate my email account to someone else, I know they should be able to see it by clicking their profile photo in the upper right of their Gmail account. But, the person I delegated to could not find my account.

I made sure, that she really did except my delegation request.   So the account should be there.

Is there another way to find a delegated account? Is there a direct link to it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't. From [Set up mail delegation - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en)

> If someone has granted you access to their account, you can access it by clicking on your profile picture or email address in the upper-right corner. Choose your delegate's email address.
>
> > **Limits**: A delegatee can access up to 10 accounts. Google Apps for Business, Education, and Government customers can access up to 512 accounts.
>
> In order to use delegation, both accounts must be enabled and verified, and neither account may require a password change on the next sign in. Otherwise, setup will fail with an error.
>
> Google Apps users can grant access to any other user in the Admin console of their organization. Only domains which have completed (or skipped) the MX record setup can be used when granting access from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ruben is correct with his answer from the 'Set up mail delegatiion - Gmail Help' article.

The extra bit that most people forget is:

> The person you added will get an email asking them to confirm. **It may
>   take up to 24 hours** for you to see them as a delegate after they
>   confirm.

This also means it might take up to 24 hours for the delegated account icon to appear. I would also suggest to either

1. Refresh the browser window (F5) or
2. logout and log back into Gmail.